# MVC 5 Url.Action pass both AjaxOptions and Route Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass both routing parameter values and AjaxOptions in a URL.Action. Doesn't this work?

I have a javascript function to refresh a partial view

```
function refreshHistory() {
    $("#id-1").load('@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { ID = "Global_ID" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "id-1" } ))'.replace('ID', Global_ID));
};
```

So this is not a valid overload for Url.Action. It is for Ajax.Actionlink but I need this to be a URL so i can load with jquery.

This kind of works. But the URL end up looking pretty wierd and the right Action in my controller is not getting called.

```
function refreshHistory() {
        $("#id-1").load('@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { ID = "Global_ID", AjaxOptions = new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "id-1" } }))'.replace('Global_ID', ID));
    };
```

URL end up looking like this: `localhost../Controller/Action?75=ID&amp;AjaxOptions=System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions` However the right target div is getting updated. But with the index action.

Comment: It does't work. There is no overload of `Html.Action` that takes `AjaxOptions`. It makes no sense.

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean. It's not Html.Action it's URL.Action. Its not a clickable link. It's a URL to load a patial view.

Comment: You want something like `$("#id-1").load('@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")', { ID = someValue })` assuming `YourAction` accepts parameter `ID`

Comment: You right I mean `Url.Action`. It dosent taks AjaxOptions as argument. I fact without AjaxOptions it sholud work.

Comment: Doesn't  required AjaxOption for UpdateTargetId.. $("#id-1").load it self load html in #id-1